# Can the Windows file open control scroll newly expanded folders into view?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

It irks me to almost no end that when I click a folder to expand it, if it's at the bottom of the list, the newly visible folders are not scrolled into view. Is there a way to change this behavior, so that the list scrolls to display the newly visible folders?

Comment: Short of reimplementing the common open dialog entirely, or getting a Windows source license so you could modify the dialog's behavior and rebuild the common controls DLL, I very much doubt it; while there are some registry hacks to change this dialog's behavior, the change you seek is complex enough that it likely requires code-level changes. Sorry; I know this isn't the answer you're looking for.

Comment: No worries; I was mostly venting.

Comment: Your edit of my title for this reason "expunge understandable but still extraneous evidence of severe annoyance on the part of the asker" - I got a kick out of that - classic!